# Custom serialize fields based on scenarios

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I'm consuming a JSON msg in the below User class. The incoming msg might look like
`{"id":1, "firstName":"ABC", "middleName":"DEF", "lastName":"GHI" }`
or
`{"id":"1", "firstName":"ABC", "middleName":"DEF", "lastName":"GHI" }`

The id part might come as String or as an int.

I have the Class User to consume this msg into

```
class User{

private String id;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
getters/setters 

}
```

How can I serialize the above object to JSON based on the scenario/request using any of the APIs available, such that

**scenario 1:**
id parameter to be serialized as Long.

```
{"id":1, "firstName":"ABC", "middleName":"DEF", "lastName":"GHI" }
```

**scenario 2:**
id parameter to be serialized as a String and ignore middleName

```
{"id":"1", "firstName": "ABC" ,"lastName" : "GHI"}
```

Comment: Why using `Object` at all? It allows anything to be right there. Why not create an abstract base class with `firstName` and `lastName` only creating two concrete classes with properly typed `id` and `middleName` for the first case? Or simply create two different classes. The second solution would work with any JSON mapping library you might use (Jackson, Gson, Moshi, etc).

Comment: @fluffy I have edited my question. To be more precise, I'm actually consuming a JSON msg from external services and directly mapping it into my User object with gson.fromJson(msg, Class), but while producing it from my end, I have these two scenarios.

Comment: One of those two solutions may work for you regardless your question updates.

Comment: @fluffy can you suggest something like using only a single class  to consume both types of msgs and while producing it back to json , we might use some filters or custom serializers based upon the scenarios.

Comment: Is it really a technical "must" for you? If I'd do it myself, I'd use separate classes for all kind of scenarios like that (even both inbound and outbound unless I'm 100% confident for using them). If you wish to stick to a single class only, the only thing you can do here is writing a custom serializer. Or manipulate JSON trees directly to get rid of mappings. Again, the overall workflow you're asking about is vague, so you choose.